# Modern way to markup 100% height layout in HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: css, html, layout

I've been away from marking up sites for some time. So, now we have HTML5 and a lot of new features in CSS. I have a common site layout with fixed size header and footer. And of course main content area in between. By default page should take 100% of window height (i.e. content area expands). And if content is long page vertical scrollbar appears and all like usual.
Usually I used to do it by something like this:

```
<body>
   <table id="main" ...>
      <tr>
         <td id="header-and-content">
            <div id="header">contains logo, nav and has fixed height</div>
            <div id="content">actual content</div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td id="footer">
           fixed size footer
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

And accompanying css:

```
html, body { height:100% }
table#main { height:100% }
td#footer { height:123px }
```

So, it's obsolete. You, who keeps abreast of new markup techniques, how it is done by now in 2011?

**UPD** People, issue not about semantic markup or using divs. I know what it does mean. Issue now in - how do I tell footer to stay at bottom even while content is empty or short. When content is long enough footer just go down as it would do in other case. Absolute and fixed is not the solution (at least at its basic form)

**SOME SUMMARY UPDATE**

1. I've tried method with usage of display:table and display:table-row and it works: [little content](http://jsfiddle.net/AHh2a/), [more content](http://jsfiddle.net/AHh2a/1/)
2. Method [Make the Footer Stick to the Bottom of a Page](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) was adviced by Andrej. It works also: [little content](http://jsfiddle.net/WcU6u/), [more content](http://jsfiddle.net/WcU6u/1/)

Some disappointment though I feel: first method is just those tables but without `table` tag. The second is really old, I've avoided to use it because it resembles hack. My god, nothing new :)

Comment: Maybe display: table and table-row/cell can help here? Anyone tried it by oneself?

Comment: For those wondering about this in the future, you might also want to take a look at the min-height attribute - it isn't perfect, but it has its use in avoiding pages that are too small to flow properly: http://www.reignwaterdesigns.com/ad/tidbits/hacks/minimum_height_in_css.shtml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, first of all in 2011 we dont use tables for layout anymore!

If I were you, I would write the markup like so:

```
<body>
   <div id="main" role="main">
        <header>
            contains logo, nav and has fixed height
        </header>
        <div class="content"> /*use <article> or <section> if it is appropriate - if not sure what to use, use a div*/
            actual content
        </div>
        <footer>
            fixed size footer
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS would be the same except the changed selectors

```
html, body { height:100% }
#main { height:100% }
footer { height:123px }
```

For a fixed footer, I would suggest to use `position:absolute` or maybe `position:fixed` - it depends how you want it to behave (scroll with page or always stay at bottom).

To make a "sticky" footer, that will be at the bottom of the page but move with the content, [this method](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) will do the trick.

Comment: tables for layouts were not-the-way-to-go already back in 2000, when IE6 came out..

Comment: You're right for what about tables. But footer is still not in bottom.

Comment: @confused-demon Footer will of course not be at the bottom by default - it will be where you want it to be. For instance: `position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0` would put it at the bottom.

Comment: If I'd do header absolute or fixed, it falls out of layout. I need it to behave just like if it was the row of table in my code example.

Comment: @confused-demon I dont know your exact code, but could it be that your parent element does not have position:relative? If so, setting position:absolute; will always put the element at the absolute position relatively to the whole browser (sorry for my English .. I hope you get what I mean).

Comment: The code is yours :) I've just colorized it some. Please, take a look at updated question.

Comment: @confused-demon I dont see me using any position attribute at all in my code... So the footer will of course not be at the bottom. Anyways, thats how my code would look if I did use it: http://jsfiddle.net/LKaKZ/ As you see, `position:absolute` will work just fine if you are not having an error somewhere else.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LKaKZ/1/ And now - not. That is the issue. You can see footer is on top of content. It should be moved by content instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LKaKZ/2/ And now - yes :) As I said, you can use `position:absolute;` or `position:fixed;` - it depends on how you want it to behave!

Comment: But it is not what is required. At your case footer overlaps content, but it should be pushed by content down when content big enough to reach footer. Fixed not an issue here.

Comment: @confused-demon: I see. I think I missunderstood your question than. What you want might be a bit more complicated, but not that hard. I think you are looking for this: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ - it will always stick at the bottom, but when content is bigger, it will scroll down with it.

Comment: yes, it works. Could you kindly update your answer to reflect this method in order to accept it?

Comment: Glad that it worked out for you! p.s. I edited my answer and included the link!

Comment: HTML and CSS still haven't completely solved the layout problem. There is nothing wrong with table layouts. In fact, they are the most supported layout by browsers and the least amount of code for most layouts.

Comment: This incomplete example fails when you add the linked missing half: once the content goes beyond 100% height the footer is floating OVER the other content.

Comment: Both Google and Twitter for exampel uses tables for there SPA's

Answer (score 7):

In 2013 there is still nothing that beats a decent table that has respectively thead/tfoot/tbody.

The below (valid HTML5 page) is a fixed header and footer, 100% height and NOT ANY resize trouble.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>valid HTML5 / fixed header and footer / nada CSS sizing trouble</title>
<style type="text/css">

html, body, table { height:                 100% }    
th {                height:                 80px }    
#f {                height:                 40px }

table {             width:                  1000px }

html, body {        margin:                 0 }
table {             margin:                 0 auto }

td {                text-align:             left }      
html, body {        text-align:             center } /* important for old browsers */
th {                text-align:             right }

html, body {        background-color:       rgb(148,0,211) } 
#m {                background-color:       #f39 }

#m {                -webkit-border-radius:  25px;    
                    -khtml-border-radius:   25px;    
                    -moz-border-radius:     25px;    
                    -ms-border-radius:      25px;      
                    -o-border-radius:       25px;      
                    border-radius:          25px; }
</style>
<table>      
  <thead><tr><th>       head</th></tr></thead>
  <tfoot><tr><td id="f">foot</td></tr></tfoot>
  <tbody><tr><td id="m">main</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kDXCw/ Any reason you use fixed width 1000px instead of 100%?

Comment: Nothing other than to clearly show it works well on sideways resizing also. But 100% width would work well to.

Comment: I was thinking about your 100% question, additionally you may might want:
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table, tr, td, th { border: 0 none transparent }

Answer (score 3):

As you asked for "modern"... anno 2016 I have maybe a better answer than in 2013:

use the 100vh solution in CSS3. vh is a new unit and stands for ViewPort height.

```css
html, body {            height:                 100% } 
header {                height:                 100px }
footer {                height:                 50px }
main {                  height:                 calc(100vh - 150px); }

html, body {            width:                  100% }  
header, main, footer {  width:                  1000px }

html, body {            margin:                 0 }
header, main, footer {  margin:                 0 auto }

html, body {            padding:                0 }

html, body {            text-align:             center }

body {                  background-color:       white } 
header {                background-color:       yellow }
main {                  background-color:       orange }
footer {                background-color:       red }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<header>bla</header>
<main>bla</main>
<footer>bla</footer>
```

But if you wish to be compatible with old browsers, use the code in my 2013 answer.

Comment: Outch! Height in `px`? Sounds like 90ths.

Answer (score 1):

Today, you would do like this (not much different really)

http://jsfiddle.net/5YHX7/3/

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; }
div { height: 100%; width: 100%; background: #F52887; }
```

and

```
<html><body><div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: But what about footer to be at the bottom? Absolute positioning?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could probably still get away with laying out your page with table tags but it is now considered bad practice.  It is considered good practice to use "semantic" web markup which means using tags for their intended purposes so a table tag should be used to represent table data and not invisible design.  DIVs are intended for use designing your invisible page layout.  A list apart is a great website resource for understanding these concepts.

This article is good for understanding semantic markup: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/12lessonsCSSandstandards

So all that said, here is a sample page that does what you want:

http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

Comment: Example page has no footer in Firefox 18

Comment: Your code does what it should and withhout a table, why is a table -like the one I published in my answer- considered bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

As asking for "modern" AND "compatible" is a contraction anyway, the grid method wasn't mentioned so far, and maybe is too modern right now, but with some adaptions might be a solution.

This article (and pointers) -with more complex use- is great to read:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/css-grid

Now the code looks nice, however browsers don't... - so I added some forcing.

https://jsfiddle.net/qLcjg6L6/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

html, body {
            height:             100%;
            min-height:         100vh;
            margin:             0;
            padding:            0 }

body {      display:            grid;
            grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, min-content) auto minmax(auto, min-content);
            grid-template-columns: 100% }

header {    background:         red }
main {      background:         pink }
footer {    background:         purple }

/* as this code is yet far from well-supported, here's a brute force... */
header {    height:             70px }
footer {    height:             60px }
main {      height:             calc(100vh - 130px); }
/* 130px being the sum of header/footer - adapt to your desired size/unit */

</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>hdr</header>
<main>main</main>
<footer>foot</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me add my contribution by adding 3 columns to your header / main / footer layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/ESrG9/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr id="header">
            <th colspan="3">head</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="left">main</td>
            <td id="main">main</td>
            <td id="right">main</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td id="footer" colspan="3">foot</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: That's not really different than my answer, but more important: your order is wrong; it's: thead, tfoot, tbody. Otherwise old browsers (at least MSIE) don't calculate correct.

Answer (score 0):

So far nobody mentioned the flex-box method

https://jsfiddle.net/55r7n9or/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

html, body, div {
            height:         100%;
            margin:         0;
            padding:        0 }

div {       display:        flex;
            flex-direction: column }

main {      flex:           1 }

header {    background:     red }
main {      background:     pink }
footer {    background:     purple }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <header>hdr</header>
  <main>main</main>
  <footer>foot</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```